# Hibernate Criteria on Two Tables - Clarification

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm reading hibernate tutorial and found some example in blogs. I try to understand the below code , Please help me for below code...

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Club.class,"club")
    .createAlias("club.team","team")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("club.name", "Arsenal"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("team.teamname", "Team A"));
    List list = criteria.list();
```

Original SQL query Looks..

```
select club.clubid, club.name, team.clubid, team.teamid, team.teamname
from Club club, Team team
where club.clubid=team.clubid and
club.name='Arsenal'
and team.teamname='Team A';
```

Here my question is :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Club.class,"club")   -   Alias for Entity
        .createAlias("club.team","team")                        -   ? 
        .add(Restrictions.eq("club.name", "Arsenal"))           -   name="Arsenal"
        .add(Restrictions.eq("team.teamname", "Team A"));       -   teamname="Team A"
```

What is happening on second line code ? Please advise..

Comment: Ohh god, your sql query is nice. Why would you try to subject it to the ugliness of criteria queries? The mismatch between the object and the relational worlds will never disappear and writing queries with the criteria api is just painful and doomed to failure. Do yourself a favor and don't use it. Criteria queries are unmaintainable and brittle. Instead write some jpaql.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html.